# what does it mean @null in style's property?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am looking at AppCompat-v7 source and I see that some properties in `values.xml` have *@null* value. What does it mean, and what are the effects on the style? Thanks.

Comment: It means... **nothing**. Yes, nothing. Say you want to set a color to... no color. Or a text to... no text. It's an object property which is **initialized** - to be nothing.